# Basic summation to formula, trying to figure out how formula was derived

Tags: summation

This comes from a coding problem on leetcode where Big O notation is being calculated.  I'm trying to understand how the left side becomes the right side here:

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {\sum_{j=i+1}^n} (j-i) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{(1+n-i)(n-i)}{2} $

Unfortunately it has been a long time since I've taken a math class, and I'm not even sure how to google this.  Specifically, how does the inner summation on the left become $ \frac{(1+n-i)(n-i)}{2} $?

Comment: Argh, actually it just came to me.  It's $\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} $ subtracting the given i.  Somehow, seeing it in a post helped.

Comment: Alternatively, it is a finite arithmetic series with first term 1, last term $n-i$, and $n-i$ terms.  So the sum (which is average of first and last times the number of terms) is $$\frac{1+(n-i)}{2}\cdot (n-i)$$.

Comment: I like to do this kind of computations using the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket#Summation_interchange) (see example).